# How to reach back to previous intent in dialogflow from current intent?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have been doing a project on dialogflow. I am building a chatbot where user is required to insert a series of information and at last the informations are sent to webhook. 
I have been building a series of followup intent for that purpose. AS like

User Name intent (Main intent)

Phone number intent ( follow up intent for username, appears after user inserts username)

I want to do is change username after receiving username and reaching phone number follow up.

For intance:

Bot: Hello Insert your username.
User: David 
Bot: You entered david as your name. **type -1 to change your name**. Enter your phone number. 
user:-1
Bot:Hello Insert your username **(Reaches to same intent)**

I need a proper solution for solving it. 
I tried with previous selection on followup but couldn't get solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Add an event to your `enter-name` intent so you can call upon it from a fulfillment function if the user typed `-1`.

Enable webhook call for your followup intent where you prompt the user for a phone number. and in your fulfillment function do something like:

```
function getPhone(agent) {
   const phoneNumber = agent.parameters.phonenumber;
   if (phoneNumber == -1) {
      agent.add(`Okey, going back`); // This won't print as the followup intent will trigger instanty but you still need to add a response to your agent.
      return agent.setFollowupEvent('change_username');
   } else {
      return agent.add(`You entered ${phoneNumber} as your phone number.`); 
   }
}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('enter-phonenumber', getPhone); // where 'enter-phonenumber' is the name of your intent which gathers phonenumbers
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

[image]

Enable webhook with: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook

You would probably want to look at something like this otherwise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxSa9g3ripQ

Where you simply move on and gather the required information and have an intent with an active context ready if the user suddenly types `by the way, my name is Eric` and catch that in there instead.

Comment: Well when the user enters -1 the webhook doesn't accept it and throws an error like response not defined because it doesnt matches any intent. I have tried fallback too but won't work

Comment: Do you have a custom entity for the phone number? Try to recognize a @sys.integer instead in that case.

Comment: Yes i tried keeping sys.number too but won't work. It throws same error

Comment: Strange, I can match "-1" on @sys.integer